# Stacking elements inside HTML Table with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-position, positioning

I'm having trouble stacking an element in a Table.

My goal is to have a table (which represents a booking calendar) with a top bar for the days, the main content that holds the bookings, and an "hours" bar on the right.

I'm trying to add a Horizontal line that corresponds to the current time and moves along...

I've added a simplified snippet of the problem I'm facing.

As you can see, the "axis" `tr` takes space and pushes the content down.
I want to stack this `tr` on top of the content & sidebar and move it using the `top` attribute.

So imagine the "main content" being attached to the top bar, and the horizontal line right in the middle, and the second `tr` eliminated

Note:
Must support IE11

```css
td{
  border: solid 1px;
}

table{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    table-layout: fixed;
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}

.axis{
  background: orange;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.top-row{
  height: 10%;
}

.top-bar{
  width: 90%;
}

.main-content{
  width: 90%;
}

.side-bar{
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="top-row" >
     <td class="top-bar" >
      Top bar
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >
      <div class="axis"> </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="main-content">
      Main Content
    </td>
     <td class="side-bar" ">
       Side bar
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: dont use tables for styling purpose. `<table>` should only be sued for tabular data. For you trying to achive is a grid layout and as such should use a `css-grid`. Alternativly it could be done with `flexbox`. CSS-grid has a limtied support for IE 11 and 13 and flexbox is supported in IE11.

Comment: Just for fun, a flexible table `table, tr { display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; width: 100%; } tbody, th, td { display: block; flex: 0 0 100%; width: 100%; }`
and then set a max-width on a `<th>` and `<td>`.
With this you can style the table cells. But as @tacoshy said, better not use table as answer to your question.